# How to generate new line character in telegram message?

Tags: php, telegram

When I send the data I read from mysql database to telegram user, the user gets underline and etc instead of new line character. So this way I can't format message text correctly.

How can I format a telegram message that is a question with 4 or more possible answers?

What else is going to be changed that I don't expect? By the way I'm sending non-english characters.

```
$qsBody = $rowQuestion['body']; // This is what I read from database that contains some new line characters
$strReply = $qsBody;
$strSendMethod = "SendMessage?chat_id=$ChatId&text='$strReply'";
file_get_contents( BOT_TARGET_ADDRESS . $strSendMethod );
// The message received by user contains _ instead of new line.
```

Comment: show some code so we can see what you have tried

Comment: I have found that you need double quotes for escape characters. For example `msg Line1\nLine2` will send one line. However, `msg "Line1\nLine2"` will send it as two separate lines.

Comment: @CodeGodie Here is the sending part code.

Comment: @Stackcrawler thanks, however, it would be helpful for you to include the actual message with the new line characters to see exactly what you're working with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it was very easy! I just had to encode message in url.

```
$qsBody = $rowQuestion['body']; // This is what I read from database that contains some new line characters
$strReply = $qsBody;
$strReply = urlencode($strReply ); // encode message
$strSendMethod = "SendMessage?chat_id=$ChatId&text='$strReply'";
file_get_contents( BOT_TARGET_ADDRESS . $strSendMethod );
// The message received by user contains _ instead of new line.
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use some code like this:

```
$text = 'hi-how are you?_im fine.lets go';
$text = str_replace(array('_', '-', '.'), chr(10), $text);
```

the code, replace underline `_`, `-` and `.` character with line break.

Answer (score 0):

sendMessage is with "s" lowercase.

```
 $qsBody = $rowQuestion['body']; // This is what I read from database that contains some new line characters
    $strReply = $qsBody; // set here your message with \n where you want a new line
    $strSendMethod = "sendMessage?chat_id=$ChatId&text='$strReply'";
    file_get_contents( BOT_TARGET_ADDRESS . $strSendMethod );
```

try here https://telegram-bot-sdk.readme.io/docs/sendmessage